# Having problem in for loop command in cmd with addition

Tags: batch-file

I am running a similar command given below in a .bat file:

```
@echo off
FOR /l %%g in (1,1,100) do (
set /a "j=%%g+1"
python main.py --s filename%%g.txt --d filename%%j.txt
)
```

Hoping for a looped command like:

```
python main.py --s filename1.txt --d filename2.txt
python main.py --s filename2.txt --d filename3.txt
... so on
```

but not getting my desired output. Please help!

Comment: You are confusing `for` meta-variables (like `%%g`) and normal environment variables (those you assign with `set`, like `j` in your code); the latter are usually accessed (expanded, read) like `%j%`, or, with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled, like `!j!`, which is required in your situation since you write and read the variable in the same line or block of code (like the body of your `for` loop); alternatively, you could precede the `python` call by the `call` command and write `%%j%%` instead of `%j%`...

Comment: can you please help me with an example code. I don't know batch-file and command line coding much. @aschipfl

Comment: As we have no idea what your python command does, I thought I'd mention that if it works on `filename1` to output to `filename2`, the very next loop will work on the new output file. It may be prudent to therefore use `(100,-1,1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do, either use addition (`+`)

a short version.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /l %%g in (1,1,100) do (
   set /a j=%%g+1
   python main.py --s filename%%g.txt --d filename!j!.txt
)
```

a longer version but creating 2 variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /l %%g in (1,1,100) do (
   set prev=%%g
   set /a curr=prev+1
   python main.py --s filename!prev!.txt --d filename!curr!.txt
)
```

Or the other way around using deduction (`-`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /l %%g in (2,1,101) do (
   set curr=%%g
   set /a prev=curr-1
   python main.py --s filename!prev!.txt --d filename!curr!.txt
)
```

in this example we set the `/l` loop to start from `2`, in sets of `1` to `101` then we deduct one value inside of the loop. Note `delayedexpansion` is needed here though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that variables evaluated before the command starts to run, and commands enclosed by  parentheses evaluated like they were in the same line.

Also, `j` is a variable, not a parameter (probably you've wanted to write `%j%` instead of `%%j`).

To address the former problem, you'll have to use the [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), and access the variable `j` using exclamation marks: `!j!`.

This will evaluate the variable as late as possible, making it work even in a for loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /l %%g in (1,1,100) do (
  set /a "j=%%g+1"
  python main.py --s filename%%g.txt --d filename!j!.txt
)
```